# Go, init custom type

Tags: initialization, go

Suppose, I am writing a minesweeper game, and i have a struct to hold the game field, that contains a 2D array with mines. Suppose, i want to initialize it with some mines. Is there a way to say `gameField GameField = new(GameField, 30)`, similar to what i'd do in java?

Here is some code to illustrate my point:

`type GameField struct {
  field [20][20] int
}`

func (this *GameField) scatterMines(numberOfMines int) {
  //some logic to place the numberOfMines mines randomly
}

What i want is to call an initializer and have that `scatterMines` func executed automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pattern I've seen in Go structs is a corresponding `NewXxx` method (e.g., [image pkg](http://golang.org/pkg/image/)):

```
type GameField struct {
  field [20][20] int
}

func NewGameField(numberOfMines int) *GameField {
  g := new(GameField)
  //some logic to place the numberOfMines mines randomly
  //...
  return g
}

func main() {
    g := NewGameField(30)
    //...
}
```

Comment: I have also seen this pattern in the form of simply have New when the package only contains one exported type. So if the package is called "gamefield" then you can just have a New function and do gamefield.New()

Answer (score 2):

Go objects have no constructors, so there is no way to have `scatterMines` function executed automatically at variable initialization. You need to call the method explicitly:

```
var GameField g
g.scatterMines(30)
```

See also http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that Go objects have no *default* constructors. You can make your own constructors but you have to call them yourself.